# Injecting a Map<String, Double> using Spring Boot and application.yml

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties

I know, there are many questions that ask similar thing in SO, but I am not able to get out of this situation using them.

I have a Spring Boot application.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class Application implements ApplicationRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application .class, args);
    }
}
```

Then I have the following class.

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "somePrefix")
public class AClass {
    private final AnotherClass anotherClass;
    private final Map<String, Double> aMap;

    @Autowired
    public AffinityChecks(AnotherClass anotherClass,
                          Map<String, Double> aMap) {
        this.anotherClass = anotherClass;
        this.aMap = aMap;
    }

    // Omissis
```

Finally I have the following `application.yml` configuration file.

```
somePrefix:
  aMap:
    key1: 0.6
    key2: 0.2
    key3: 0.2
```

All I want is Spring to inject the map into object of type`AClass` during building process. The error I obtain is the following.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Double>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

What the hell is going on?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to delete "Map<String, Double> aMap" from constructor. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-complex-type-merge

Comment: If I remove the map from the constructor the error goes away, because `aMap` is not initialized by Spring anymore ;)

Comment: You may need to add getter for your Map

Comment: Reading the doc should help: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties - We don't support constructor injection, your properties need to be javabean properties ( so a getter and a setter with the exception of maps and nested, i.e. non scalar, values that only require a getter).

Comment: @StephaneNicoll you're right. This solves my problem. If you want to answer the question, I will accept it. Thanks

Comment: Just for curiosity can you make a little change like instead of Map pass HashMap<String, Double> in the AffinityChecks argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Boot does not support constructor injection for elements that are bound to the environment. You can of course inject actual beans the usual way.

You need to define each property you want to bind as a regular Javabean property (i.e. with getter/setter). There is one exception to this rule: Maps and non-scalar value (i.e. nested content) only need a getter.

Concretely if `AnotherClass` is a bean and `FooClass` some pojo with nested properties.

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "somePrefix")
public class AClass {
    private final AnotherClass anotherClass;
    private final Map<String, Double> aMap = new HashMap<>();
    private final FooClass foo = new FooClass();

    public AClass(AnotherClass anotherClass) { ...}

    public Map<String, Double> getaMap() { ... }

    public FooClass getFoo() { ... }

}
```

(Note that the getter is the thing that infers the name of the property. In the example above you could map `somePrefix.foo.xyz` if you had a `getXyz()` on `FooClass`).

There is an example [in the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties) with additional details.

(A good hint that your code is wrong is that the map is not a bean so `@Autowiring` isn't the proper semantic for what you were trying to achieve).

Comment: `AnotherClass` **is** a bean. In fact I do not like very much not to use the constructor injection in this case :(

Comment: you can inject anotherclas then. no problem. We do not support constructor injects for the things to bind. I've updated my answer.

Comment: That's exactly what I've done. Thanks. However I think that the best solution would be to encapsulate all the values read from the configuration file inside a dedicated object (not in the business type `AClass`)

Comment: Well it's your code, I provided an example with what you gave me. I don't think injecting collaborators in configurationproperties is a good idea.